# Where does the factor 1.3 for Vapp come from?

Tags: approach, instrument-procedures, v-speeds

The approach speed Vapp is usually given as 1.3 * Vs0, or 1.3 times the stall speed in landing configuration.

Why 1.3? What created a consensus of 1.3 * Vs0 as the generally accepted textbook approach speed?

Comment: I don't have time to pull proper research, but it's looking light it may just have been an arbitrary *"130% of stall speed in the landing configuration"*, safety margin from 1941 Aviation Regs that got translated into 1.3 Vs0 in the next few years' editions and have stuck since.

Comment: @ryan Mortensen thanks, very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

1.3 Vso is not a universal rule even for the same plane.  First is extra weight, which requires higher AOA for adequate lift at the same speed, or greater speed at the same AOA. Approach a little faster if heavy.  Next is CG.  If CG is near limits, a little extra speed will help aerodynamic trim as you slow down.  Finally, there is weather. Gusting winds or wind gradient (head wind dropping as you near the ground) should make the pilot consider adding a few knots to approach speed as well.

The best policy is to do what is safe for your plane.  A very slow plane that lands at 25 knots may be more like 1.5 or higher, especially on a windy day.

1.3 Vso is a fairly good approximation for a plane that stalls around 50 knots, approaching 
at 65 knots.

Another consideration in approach is safely banking in the pattern.  Stall speed increases with bank angle as follows.

Load factor G = 1/(cos bank angle)
Stall Speed (Accelerated) = Vs x Square Root G

For 30 degree bank:  G = 1/.8662 = 1.155  (thought I had it here for a second!)
               Accelerated stall speed = Vs x 1.07

For 45 degree bank:  G = 1/.7071 = 1.414
               Accelerated stall speed = Vs x 1.18

For 60 degree bank:  G = 1/.5000 = 2.000
              Accelerated stall speed = Vs x 1.414

So we avoid steep turns in landing patterns as well!  Yet another reason to add safety margin 
to approach speed.

Comment: You aren't *wrong*, but you did not answer his question.  Since, clearly, every situation is different as you've pointed out. *Why is 1.3 the **textbook** number?*

Comment: The point is textbook theory does not fly a plane.  And I would like to know which textbook you are referring to.  And yes, we have not discussed flaps yet.  But the point is there is enough variation to get qualified opinions and training to be safe for the type of aircraft one pilots.  Now the faster one gets, the farther 1.3 gets away from stall speed. Example stall at 100, 1.3 x 100 = 130.  Stall at 30, 1.3 x 30 = 39.  This can be crucial at slow speeds in wind.  So where do we get 1.3 ???

Comment: Where do we get 1.3 is the OP's question.

Comment: The "textbook" answer of either Vref or (1.3*Vs0) if Vref isn't published is found in the AIM. 5-4-7 first and second sentence regarding approach category of aircraft.

Comment: Ok, I'll go with that and a NOTAM for people who approach slower than trainers such as the Cessna 172.  See math in my edit, and thanks for getting me to dig a little more.

Comment: Even that portion of the AIM does not explain -- *Why 1.3?*  I would give my own answer, but I haven't because I don't know the answer to the specific, *why?*, question asked.  Otherwise, I would be giving an opinion-based guess without documentation, which isn't appropriate for this format.

Comment: Well, realizing there is not a universal approach speed is constructive.  I have listed several reasons why a pilot should at least be aware of this issue.  I hope my edits have helped.